# Change reply address in Outlook mail

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Excel sheet with three columns Employee Name, Email ID and DOB.

I wrote a macro which matches birth dates of the employees with today's date that will send an Outlook mail To the employee and Cc my department.

When all the employees see that mail they can click on reply or reply to all.

I wrote another Outlook macro which replaces To address field with his/her birthday person email id.

The second macro is working on my system on any Outlook email which is open.

Because I have the Outlook macro I am able to execute it but to perform same thing in all the employees systems they need this Outlook macro. How can I run it in their systems without putting this macro in their systems manually?

Comment: If you have spaces at the beginning of a line, the line is formatted as code.  I have removed the spaces so your question can be read.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 9):

The following code assumes ObjMail is the message you are creating.

```
' Delete any existing reply recipients
Do While ObjMail.ReplyRecipients.Count > 0
  ObjMail.ReplyRecipients.Remove 1
Loop

' Add the new recipient
ObjMail.ReplyRecipients.Add "BirthdayPerson@isp.com"

' Send blind copy to other staff members
ObjMail.BCC = "Staff1.isp.com, Staff2.isp.com, Staff3.isp.com"
```

The message sent to staff will say it has come from whoever sends the birthday messages.  But if anyone replies, the recipient will be "BirthdayPerson@isp.com".

I have sent blind copies to other staff members.  This is not because the staff list is secret but because:

- If you have 500 staff members with an average 20 characters per address, use of CC would add 10,000 characters to each of 500 messages.
- It prevents staff using Reply All when adding their best wishes saving another 500 * 500 messages.
- Use ObjMail.CC if you would prefer to fill your company's server.

I worry about message size because many years ago I worked for the English NHS which had thousands of employees scattered across the country.  Someone at a small hospital tried to advertise his bicycle for sale within the hospital but managed to advertise it to every employee in the country.  I worked from home with a slow dial-up line; it took half-an-hour to download this message.

**New section in response to request for full code of test routine**

Below I include the full routine I used to test my answer.  It was adapted from a routine I wrote for another answer.  It creates an HTML body which you may not want but shows you how if you do.  I have replaced the real email addresses I used for my tests with dummy addresses; otherwise it is unchanged.

```
Sub ReplyToRecipientWithBlindCopies()

  ' Create a mail item with a simple message.
  ' Send the mail item to "BirthdayPerson@isp.com" and make them
  ' the recipient of any replies.
  ' Send blind copies to all other recipients.

  ' Author: Tony Dallimore, York, England

  Dim OlApp As Outlook.Application
  Dim ObjMail As Outlook.MailItem

  Dim MessageBody As String

  ' This creates a blue message on a grey background.  This is a
  ' demonstration of what is possible; not a recommendation!
  MessageBody = "<table width=""100%"" style=""Color:#0000FF;" & _
         " background-color:#F0F0F0;""><tr><td align= ""center"">" & _
         "Happy birthday from all your colleagues!</td></tr></table>"

  Set OlApp = Outlook.Application
  Set ObjMail = OlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  With ObjMail
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .Subject = "Happy birthday!"
    .HTMLBody = HeadAndBodyToHtmlDoc("", MessageBody)

    ' Remove any existing recipients
    Do While .Recipients.Count > 0
      .Recipients.Remove 1
    Loop
    ' Remove any existing reply recipients
    Do While .ReplyRecipients.Count > 0
      .ReplyRecipients.Remove 1
    Loop

    ' Add birthday person to Recipient and ReplyRecipient lists
    .Recipients.Add "BirthdayPerson@isp.com"
    .ReplyRecipients.Add "BirthdayPerson@isp.com"

    ' You will need to replace this with a loop
    ' to add all your staff members.
    .BCC = "Staff1@isp.com, Staff2@isp.com, Staff3@isp.com"

    ' Display the prepared messages ready for any final changes.
    ' The user must send it.
    .Display
  End With

End Sub
Function HeadAndBodyToHtmlDoc(Head As String, Body As String) As String

  ' Wrap Head and Body created by caller in a standard envelope.

  ' Author: Tony Dallimore, York, England

  HeadAndBodyToHtmlDoc = _
        "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN""" & _
        " ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd"">" & _
        vbCr & vbLf & "<html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""" & _
        " xml:lang=""en"" lang=""en"">" & vbCr & vbLf & "<head><meta " & _
        "http-equiv=""Content-Type"" content=""text/html; " & _
        "charset=utf-8"" />" & vbCr & vbLf & Head & vbCr & vbLf & _
        "</head><body>" & vbCr & vbLf & Body & "</body></html>"

End Function
```

Comment: The extra section in my answer should give the extra information you seek.  If my answer meets your requirements, I would appreciate it if you accepted it.

Comment: No what i asking is those b'day emails will sent from an unknown email to all employees. The code which u wrote works well but that macro is working in my outlook. I need that to work in all employees outlooks when they click on the b'day email reply or reply all button. For that i need to send this code in a macro to all employees with that auto generated mail only. How can i send this macro with that email.......

Comment: I do not understand. You have an Excel workbook containing the names, email addresses and birthdays of staff members. You had a macro that will send an email to staff members on their birthday saying "Happy birthday!" I have provided information to allow you to make minor improvements to that macro so now other staff members can click "Reply" and send a message saying "Happy birthday from me as well!" Your macro is within the Excel workbook and relies on information in that workbook. Why would you want to email that macro to anyone? You would need to email the workbook.

Comment: As you said its all correct but the macro which i had in my excel workbook will send emails to all employees which states these r the employees had birthdays on this day. But now i had another macro which changes the reply address when any employee click on reply button on the email which he got. I am asking how can i execute that second macro in the employees systems.

Comment: How to distribute a macro is a different question. One possibility is to distribute the code and get staff to install it themselves. Another possibility is get your IT Department to distribute it with their next rebuild if they organise your software that way. I am sure there are other possibilities but this is not my area of expertise and this may not be the best part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: However, is this part of the same "Birthday wishes" system? The code I gave you sets the reply-to address to the birthday boy/girl's email address. I tested this code by sending emails to the four email addresses shared by my wife and myself. The emails will say they were sent by you but if you click Reply, the email will be addressed to the birthday person. Set your system to send emails to two or three people and try it.

Comment: Yes it's part of u birthday wishes. You said you tested with four email addresses thats what i am also saying i tested i its working fine. The problem is you r testing the things in the same system try to test like this send emails to four email id's and open their outlooks in different systems and test with out placing any macro their......

Comment: Hey i have one more doubt how its working for Reply to ALL i have two addresses in when i click on reply to all button but only one address is i am able to remove and its replacing 2 times the mail id which we gave but actually the email address which i need its already there

Comment: My internet connection is being upgraded and I may not be able to reply again until Monday.  Why use "Reply-to-all"?  I tried "Reply" on two different systems and only the Birthday person's address was shown.  I have just tried "Reply-to-all" and only got the Birthday person's address.  Where are the extra addresses coming from?  Are you placing extra addresses in Recipient or CC?

Comment: Yes I have Address in CC field also hey can u post full code here

Comment: Tony u misunderstand my question partially ..........the code which u pasted is creating a new outlook mail thats perfect....that is not my question i can create all those things .........i will explain once again my question once again......check once my first post

Comment: I do not understand what macro needs to be run on all the separate systems.  However, as I said two days ago: "How to distribute a macro is a different question."