# olMailItem - ReplyRecipients.Add

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba, ms-access-2013

I am in MS Access 2013 trying to set the Reply To address for a olMailItem with Outlook 2013.

My current code is giving me:

Run-time error '287'
Application-defined or object-defined error

```
Private Sub email_button_click()

' *** SETUP OUTLOOK ***
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set OutApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

' *** DO SOME OTHER STUFF ****
....

With OutMail
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Whatever"
    .To = "test@test.com"
    .ReplyRecipients.Add "notatest@test.com"    <- Error here
    .Display
End With

' *** TIDY UP ***
Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Plenty of others seem to be able to do it. ie :

[Change reply address in Outlook mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9259325/change-reply-address-in-outlook-mail)

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=186882

http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-19993.html

Thanks

Doug

Comment: Are you trying to add someone to the CC? If you are, you can use Outmail.CC = "Email@Something.com"

Comment: @RyanWildry: *"trying to set the **Reply To** address"*

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no problem running the following script in Outlook VBA or OutlookSpy (I am its author) script editor.

```
Set OutMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With OutMail
    .Subject = "Test"
    .Body = "Whatever"
    .To = "test@test.com"
    .ReplyRecipients.Add "notatest@test.com"
    .Display
End With
```

If Outlook is not running, make sure you call Namespace.Logon fist:

```
set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
ns.Logon
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on a Enterprise system where the group policy was blocking VBA scripts on Outlook 2013.

The solution is to turn the GP off.

Answer (score 0):

Just list it a second time, you are "adding" recipiants

```
   .ReplyRecipients.Add "notatest1@test.com"
   .ReplyRecipients.Add "notatest2@test.com"
```